# setting start scripts in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

locally, i start my app using the following commands:

```
cd react-web
sudo npm run postinstall
export REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_ENVIRONMENT=envvariable
npm start
```

So, now i want to push this live through heroku. BUT, i need to set the start scripts in my package.json

so i have two `package.json`, one in the root directory, and one in `react-web`.

in the root directory, i wrote this start-script:

```
    "scripts": {
    "test-web": "cd react-web && npm test && cd ..",
    "test": "npm run test-web",
    "start": "cd react-web && export REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_ENVIRONMENT=gianlucaherokutest && npm start"
  },
```

and in the `react-web` `package.json`, this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node checkEnvironmentForBuild && react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "node checkEnvironmentForBuild && react-app-rewired build",
    "deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://YOUR_S3_DEPLOY_BUCKET_NAME --delete",
    "postdeploy": "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOUR_CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*' && aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOUR_WWW_CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*'",
    "postinstall": "npm link ../shared",
    "test": "node checkEnvironmentForBuild && react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

can someone give me some advice on why it isn't working? When I run the app using everything above, it gives me this error:

```
2021-04-19T21:12:11.796818+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

any ideas?

Comment: seems like it is out of memory, could be due to an infinite loop. any other. errors?

Comment: @Gianluca no, that is the only error. I tried adding this `--max_old_space_size=2560` in the react-web start script, but nothing changed

Comment: are you running this in a container or your local machine?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili I am running it locally, but once i push to heroku, it should run these scripts